# "Successful" response from API is just Success: True, no data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, express, proxy, vuejs3

I have my app setup, and running on an express server with a proxy to talk to the API server, my code is outlined below

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Is That Legit?</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <header>
          <img alt="Site logo" class="logo" src="assets/logo.svg" width="333" height="187" />
        </header>
        <h1 class="app-title">Is User Legit</h1>
        <input @input="saveID" placeholder="User ID" />
        <button @click="checkID">Check Customer is Legit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.4.9/dist/vue.global.js" defer></script>
    <script src="app.js" defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My App.js is setup like this, fairly standard:

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      customerID: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    saveID(event) {
      this.customerID = event.target.value;
    },
    async checkID() {
      const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'x-api-key': 'ThisIsMyAPIKeyThereIsNoOtherLikeIt'
        }
      }
      const url = `/checkCustomer?customerNumber=${this.customerID}`;
      try {
        const result = await fetch(url, options);
        const json = await result.json();
        console.log(json);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    },
  }
})

app.mount('#app')
```

my server.js (which is powered by ExpressJS) is also below...

```
const express = require('express');
const https = require('https');
const cors = require('cors');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();

// app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static('dist'));
app.use('/dist', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + 'dist/index.html');
});
app.use('/dist/assets/main.css', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + 'dist/assets/main.css');
});
app.use(express.json());
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ['https://myAPI.com'],
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
  })
);
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With')
  res.status(200).json({ success: true});
  next()
});

// Add middleware for http proxy
const options = {
    target: 'https://myAPI.com', // target host
    pathRewrite: {
        '^/checkCustomer' : ''
    },
    router: {
        'localhost:3000': 'https://myAPI.com',
    },
};
const apiProxy = (req, res) => {
    createProxyMiddleware(options);
}
app.use('/checkCustomer', apiProxy);

https.createServer(
    {
        key: fs.readFileSync("thisIsMyServerKey.key"),
        cert: fs.readFileSync("thisIsMyServerCert.cert"),
    },
    app
).listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Listening on: https://localhost:3000');
});
```

So I run `npm run start` to fire up my `server.js` no problem, and the aim is to populate the input box with a customer ID and hit the "Are They Legit?" button to check if a customer is real or not, the proxy jumps in checking for the `/checkCustomer` it then removes the `/checkCustomer` and appends the rest of the URL tot he API url and submits it.

However this doesn't appear to be the case, and I just get `{success: true}` in the console. I don't get any response data, and I don't get any indication as to the fact that anything is wrong.

everything is currently configured the way it is to try and resolve an issue with CORS.

I tried a few articles/Q&A on stackOverflow, googling a few solutions, but nothing has come to fruition, this was the closest I have got.

Would someone be able to guide me in fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code runs unconditionally, regardless of the URL:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With')
  res.status(200).json({ success: true}); // <============================ Note!
  next()
});
```

As you can see, it sends a response. So it's getting in the way of your code that's specific to the API URL `/checkCustomer`.

You probably want to remove the `res.status(200).json({ success: true});` statement. Or if you want it for other URLs, you'll want to make it conditional or similar.

---

Separately: I've never used that proxy middleware, but it seems like `apiProxy` should *return* the result of `createProxyMiddleware` so the proxy goes to `app.use`. (Currently `apiProxy` doesn't return anything, because an arrow function with a `{` just after the `=>` uses a full function body, so you'd need a `return` to return the result of the `createProxyMiddleware` call.)